# How to increase the width of table header and table cell in JavaFX Tableview

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-tableview

How to increase the spacing of table header and table cell in JavaFX.

I have created my table like below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewExample extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TableView tableView = new TableView();

    TableColumn<Person, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));


    TableColumn<Person, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));


    tableView.getColumns().add(column1);
    tableView.getColumns().add(column2);

    tableView.getItems().add(new Person("John", "Doe"));
    tableView.getItems().add(new Person("Jane", "Deer"));

    VBox vbox = new VBox(tableView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, do you want wider cells (more padding around the words) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the width of the columns then use:

```java
column1.setMinWidth(100);
```

If you want to increase the spacing between the header and the data rows. then you could add some empty rows like this:

```java
tableView.getItems().add(new Person("", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @sorifiend mentioned in the comment. You need to be a bit more elaborative with the question about what kind of spacing you are seeking for.

If you are asking for how to enlarge the cell/header, one way is you can do it by changing the css values.

Add your css stylesheet as below:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("table.css").toExternalForm());
```

And include the below css in the table.css file:

```
.table-cell, .column-header.table-column .label{
  -fx-padding:10px;
}
```

[image]